# Unit Testing Android Utility Functions

Tags: android

So, I am relatively new to Android and am trying to sort out how to do decent unit testing of my code.  I am trying to write a unit test for a simple utility function that copies files from the assets over to the internal file system,

```
public class FileUtils {
    private static String LOG_TAG = "FileUtils";
    public static void copyAssetToInternalStorage(Context ctxt, final String assetName, final String filePath) 
        throws IOException {
...
        File filesDir = ctxt.getFilesDir();
        File outFile = new File(filesDir, filePath);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Internal File Path: " + outFile.getAbsolutePath());
...
    }
}
```

In my test project I have the test,

```
public class FileUtilsTest 
    extends InstrumentationTestCase {

    public void testCopyAsset() {
        String ASSET_FILE = "TestFile_1.txt";
            String DEST_FILE_1 = "DestFile_1.txt";

        Context ctxt = this.getInstrumentation().getContext();

        try {
            FileUtils.copyAssetToInternalStorage(ctxt, ASSET_FILE, DEST_FILE_1);

            File filesDir = ctxt.getFilesDir();
            File tstFile1 = new File(filesDir, DEST_FILE_1);

            Assert.assertTrue("Output file does not exist", tstFile1.exists());
            Assert.assertEquals("Output file is not the correct size", 
                    154, tstFile1.length());

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Assert.fail("Exception: " + ex.getClass() + ": " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I have the asset used as the input for the test in the assets directory in the test project, hence the use of the this.getInstrumentation().getContext() for the context I am working under for the test.

When I run the test, if finds the asset just fine, but when the function tries to write to the internal file system the call to ctxt.getFilesDir() is logging an error.  What I see using "adb logcat" is this,

```
application com.perigee.brewing.recipeeditor: pid=803 uid=10037 gids={}
I/TestRunner(  803): started: testCopyAsset(com.perigee.utils.FileUtilsTest)
W/ApplicationContext(  803): Unable to create files directory /data/data/com.perigee.brewing.recipeeditor.test/files
D/FileUtils(  803): Copying asset to internal file; assetName[TestFile_1.txt], internalFile[DestFile_1.txt]
W/ApplicationContext(  803): Unable to create files directory /data/data/com.perigee.brewing.recipeeditor.test/files
D/FileUtils(  803): Internal File Path: /DestFile_1.txt
W/System.err(  803): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /DestFile_1.txt (Read-only file system)
...
```

Is there a better way to do this type of testing?  Can data not be written to the internal file system in the test project?

Bottom line, if any one has any suggestions on how to test this I would appreciate it...  I have not been able to find much in the way of examples for testing this basic level of utility functions that require the use of the Context.  I have found a few references to testing whole utility libraries, but little details on managing the context in the tests.

Comment: I ran across this issue, (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8886), but this sounds like it is much more random that what I am seeing.  My case fails every time...